# Hostname changed without syslog restart

Tags: linux, unix

I wish to know is there any way I can changed hostname without restarting the syslog 
As I want the changed hostname to be reflected in the syslog messages.

Thanks
Arpit

Answer (score 1):

you can try `kill -HUP <pid of syslog daemon>`. get the pid of syslog daemon using `ps`